# OpenCV with Google Glass Library/Manager issue

Tags: android, c++, opencv, google-glass

I'm creating a face detection/recognition app for Google Glass and every time that I try to run the program it says that `OpenCV manager` is not installed and asks me to try and install it. When I click yes it says that it failed.

I also attempted to use terminal to install `OpenCV manager` and this didn't fix the issue.  I then decided to try and do static initialization and followed the steps here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization
and included the libraries I am using in my libs folder but it still doesn't work.

The app has no jni folder so there is no `android.mk` or `application.mk` files to alter.

Has anyone figured out how to do use this on Google Glass and can help me out?

If there is anything else I could include to help you help me let me know!

Answer (score 0):

When you say use terminal to install it, you do mean that you did adb install, right?  If so, which .apk hve you installed?

I have openCV working on my glass and I have:

- org.opencv.engine
- org.opencv.lib_v24.armv7a

in my install packages (`adb shell pm list packages`)

I forgoet which I installed first, but it did not work.  I had to install both (I have no clue why).

I hope that helps a little.

Comment: I m not using terminal to install, Im trying to install the sample app, I m getting the same error..